# Glassfish 3.1.2.2 changes it's default login realm after some time

Tags: java, authentication, glassfish

I'm currently working on a client-server application that uses `ProgrammaticLogin` to authenticate the client-users against the server. `Glassfish` is set up with a default realm that authenticates through an `ActiveDirectory`. We recently upgraded the version of glassfish from `3.0.1` to `3.1.2.2`, and now we are experiencing a strange bug: After some time running, seemingly randomly, the default security realm is changed to `file`, instead of the `ActiveDirectory`-realm! Needless to say, this inhibits people's ability to log in from the client. When glassfish is restartet, it starts working again, correctly using the `ActiveDirectory`-realm to authenticate.

Does anyone know what could cause such behavior from `Glassfish`? Could it be a disconnect from the `AD`-realm or something?

Excerpt from the stacktrace after the error is in effect:

```
Programmatic login failed
com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Failed file login for me.
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:394)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:240)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:153)
    at com.sun.appserv.security.ProgrammaticLogin$1.run(ProgrammaticLogin.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.appserv.security.ProgrammaticLogin.login(ProgrammaticLogin.java:168)
    at com.sun.appserv.security.ProgrammaticLogin.login(ProgrammaticLogin.java:239)
    at com.sun.appserv.security.ProgrammaticLogin.login(ProgrammaticLogin.java:211)
    [...]
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Failed file login for me.
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.FileLoginModule.authenticate(FileLoginModule.java:84)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.PasswordLoginModule.authenticateUser(PasswordLoginModule.java:117)
    at com.sun.appserv.security.AppservPasswordLoginModule.login(AppservPasswordLoginModule.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:382)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the error occured in one of our test-environment (curiously, it occured at pretty much the same time in 3 different environments, with 3 different ldaps), I was able to debug and get closer to a solution.

First, we checked the default realm in domain.xml at the time of the error, and it was still pointing at our AD-realm, not file.

When playing around with debugger, the following gave an exception after trying to log in with file:

```
new ProgrammaticLogin().login(username, password);
new ProgrammaticLogin().login(username, password, "default", true);
```

These two are equivalent, and both leave it up to the server to determine what the default realm is. When specifying the name of the AD-realm I wanted to authenticate against on the other hand, it worked like a charm:

```
new ProgrammaticLogin().login(username, password, "myRealm", true);
```

So it seems that we have a bug in Glassfish 3.1.2.2, that makes glassfish confused as to what is the default login-realm.

As a side-note (or two), for two of the environments that were affected, the problem solved itself after a few minutes. Also, just going into the glassfish admin console, and changing the default realm to file, and then back to the AD-realm also fixed the problem. (Possibly just saving the page would have the same effect.)

Comment: Interesting. We have been running Glassfish 3.1.2.2 in development as well as production for more than a year without any problem. We use a custom database realm. Are you sure that your realm initialized always without problems?